# All sorts of trouble with SSL offloaded via Cloudflare

Tags: magento2, ssl

We are setting up a new Magento 2.1.5, and use CloudFlare for some protection and offloaded SSL.

I have set Base URL to `http://shop.shmakerspace.org` and Secure Base to `https://shop.shmakerspace.org`

I set the Offload header to `X-Forwarded-Proto`, and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` and `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` to no avail.

We also set the following in the .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

When I then apply that and clear all caches, the whole site goes crazy due to 404 errors for the static content.

I put a test.php with the `phpinfo()` in the site root, and I can see the `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header, and also that `HTTPS=on`

Comment: Do you have SSL certs on your site or are you only using Cloudflare's? You need both.

Comment: Why do I need both? That's not how CF works. That's the whole point of SSL  offloading.

Comment: Cloudflare SSL PM here. Unless you're using Flexible mode (see SSL setting on Crypto tab) which terminates SSL/TLS at the browser and then communicates to your origin in plaintext, you're going to need a certificate on your origin. You can generate a free one using our Origin CA offering (further down that page) or install something like Let's Encrypt.

Comment: We are using flexible. I think we've narrowed our down to something to do with content compression or rocket. With all of that disabled, it seems to sort of start working.